# Каким запросом можно посмотреть загрузку сервера Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

Какой запрос сделать, чтобы посмотреть какие процедуры грузят сервер Oracle в данный момент? Как убить ресурсоемкие процедуры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с 10g версии на сервере по умолчанию поднимается веб-сервер:

```
https://localhost.localdomain:1158/em
```

EM - enterprise manager.

Там можно посмотреть графики загрузки и что конкретно его грузит.

---

PS прим.ред.: с 12.1.0.1 поставляется облегчённая версия EM Express.

Answer (score 4):

> Как убить ресурсоемкие процедуры?

Такой возможности нет. Начиная с 18c можно [прекратить выполненее запроса](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-processes.html#GUID-7D8E5E00-515D-4338-8B86-C2044F6D2957), который выполняет процедура, до того, можно было "убить" только всю сессию.

Из статистики сессий можно узнать, какая активная сессия занимала больше всего процессорного времени:

```
select
   s.username, t.sid, s.serial#, round (sum (value/100)) "Cpu usage (sec.)"
from v$session s, v$sesstat t, v$statname n
where t.sid = s.sid 
and t.statistic# = n.statistic#
and name like '%CPU used by this session%'
and s.status='ACTIVE'
and s.username is not null
group by username, t.sid, s.serial# 
order by "Cpu usage (sec.)" desc
/
```

Вывод будет примерно выглядеть так:

```
USERNAME        SID    SERIAL# Cpu usage (sec.)
-------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
ME               47      64670             2122
SYS               6       2187                0
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать [TOAD for Oracle](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/) , там вроде есть PL/SQL профайлер.

Comment: Либо юзать DBMS_PROFILER.